# Author name of \textcite as possessive

Tags: biblatex, citing

When using `biblatex` I often use `\textcite`. Sometimes I want to write things like "Smith's (2000) formulation of x is" instead of "Smith (2000) formulates x as". How do I achieve this? Or more generally, how do I make the author's name output by `\textcite` to be in the [possessive case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_%28linguistics%29)? I'm mainly looking for an English variant. This means that I want `\textcite` to be able to add "'s" to the author's name, e.g. to output

> Knuth's (1984)

instead of

> Knuth (1984)

Ideally I want a solution to be able to put any author's or authors' name in the possessive case and for it to be able to cope with other languages than English.

The following example might clarify what I'm asking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@book{texbook,
    author  = {Donald E. Knuth},
    title   = {The {{\TeX}book}},
    publisher   = {Addison-Wesley},
    date    = {1984}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{database.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{texbook}% Standard use. Output: "Knuth (1984)"

\textcite{texbook}'s% Failed try to get output in the possesive case. Output: "Knuth (1984)'s"

Knuth's (1984)% The ouput that I want

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the kind of references I'm trying to use conflict with convention or publishers?

Comment: `\citeauthor{texbook}'s \citeyear{texbook}` should work?

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14785/possessive-cite-in-biblatex-chicago-authordate).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This answer extends [Philipp Lehman's method](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2843496&group_id=244752&atid=1126006) for generating a possessive `labelname` using a format alias. It should work for all variants of the standard author-year styles.

Note that the solution is bad for plural labelnames, where the possessive is formed with just `'` and not `'s`. This case is probably very rare, though. Other languages may not be as easy to handle. For an example refer to [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14785/4483), which considers Norwegian possessives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname:poss}{% Based on labelname from biblatex.def
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}{'s}{}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}{#1's}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{#1}'s}

\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{#1's}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{shorthand}{shorthand:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{citetitle:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{label}{label:poss}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscite}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcite}

\newrobustcmd*{\Posscite}{\bibsentence\posscite}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscites}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcites}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{bertram:sa,
  author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  shortauthor = {BW},
  title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume = {9},
  number = {2},
  date = {1996},
  pages = {529--571}}
@Book{title,
  title = {A Book with No Author},
  date = {1933}}
@Book{shorthand,
  title = {A Book with No Author},
  shorthand = {ABWNA},
  date = {1933}}
@Book{label,
  label = {Fallback label},
  date = {1933}}
@Book{does,
  title = {A Book by the Does},
  author = {Doe, John and Doe, Jane},
  shortauthor = {{The Does}},
  date = {1990}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{cite with labelname}
posscite many authors: \posscite[3036]{aksin} \\
textcite shortauthor: \textcite[e.g.][3]{bertram:sa} \\
posscite shortauthor: \posscite[e.g.][4]{bertram:sa} \\
textcite shorthand: \textcite{kant:ku} \\
posscite shorthand: \posscite{kant:ku} \\
textcite compact: \textcite{aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics} \\
posscite compact: \posscite{aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics} \\
textcites: \textcites[3036]{aksin}[529]{bertram:sa} \\
posscites: \posscites[3036]{aksin}[529]{bertram:sa} \\
posscite with plural labelname (where this solution is bad): \posscite{does}
\subsection*{cite without labelname}
textcite shorthand: \textcite{shorthand} \\
posscite shorthand: \posscite{shorthand} \\
textcite title: \textcite{title} \\
posscite title: \posscite{title} \\
textcite label: \textcite{label} \\
posscite label: \posscite{label} \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. I really appreciate that your solution seems to handle prenote and postnote just like any other biblatex cite command. Maybe someone should post this answer to the biblatex author so that possessive cites may be considered for implementation. I was worried that this question was too similar to the related question domwass posted but when a solution like this surfaces it seems to be a justified question.

Comment: @N.N. The solution relies on `\DeclareCiteCommand` to do all the work. Prenotes would appear within the parentheses as they do with `\textcite`. If you want the prenote to appear before the labelname/label, similar edits could be applied to the commands in `authoryear-comp.cbx` that define `\cite`. Possessive citations would be a nice feature to have, but a language-specific implementation would be a tall order.

Comment: You're wrong about plural label names. Both Strunk & White and the Chicago Manual of Style (16th ed., 7.17) say the possessive of The Does is The Does's.

Comment: @user14774 There is no wrong or right for exceptions to the general rule of adding `'s`. Read further in CMS (e.g. section 7.19).

Comment: This is nice, though it unfortunately permits the line to be broken between the author name and year.  [The usual solution to this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74931/biblatexs-textcite-inserts-a-breaking-space-between-author-names-and-citation-n), `\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}{\addspace}{\addnbspace}{}{}`, doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone suggest how @Audrey's `\posscite` can be adapted so that it uses a nonbreaking space between the `'s` and the year?

Comment: @Psychonaut The possessive citation isn't the problem. That solution was intended for the numeric styles. Under author-year the `texcite` bibliography macro has more than one instance of `\addspace`, so it will have to be patched twice.

Comment: Thanks, Audrey.  However, it seems your original answer no longer works at all now, at least in Biblatex 3.3, due to [a recent change to the format of `\DeclareNameFormat`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299084/22603).  Perhaps you might consider revising your solution?

Comment: I got also hit by the Biblatex 3.3 changes. I'm a little bit lost on how to adapt this valuable piece of code.

Comment: I have adapted Audrey's code for Biblatex 3.3 and 3.4 and posted it [as a separate answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307461/22603).

Comment: Is there a way to show the page number with posscite? For example, "Smith's (1954, p. 35) procedure ..."

Answer (score 18):

You could always define a "possessive cite" command yourself as follows:

```
\newcommand\posscite[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
```

Although I can't promise it would look pretty or work properly for multiple author works...

Of course, properly speaking what you should do is use `biblatex`'s own `\DeclarCiteCommand` and friends interface (and replace the parentheses with the right macro so that if you change the type of parens used, they change too...)

Comment: Ad for other languages, I guess you could patch into those parts of `babel` or `polyglossia` that deal with possessives? But as a near-monoglot I have no experience of those packages...

Comment: Indeed, I'm curious how this will work for multiple authors. I'm not even sure how multiple authors are written in the possessive case in English or how the possessive case is handled when the author's names are shortened with "et al.".

Comment: @N.N. A quick look at Chicago Manual of Style (16th ed.) suggests that it should be "Foo and Bar's (1999) work" for example. Can't find comments on what to do with _et al_...

Comment: I like your solution, but when I use it, the hyperlink from the citation to the bibliography is missing. Do you know how to get the hyperlink back?

Comment: @Seamus thanks. I compile the above latex. However, it does not do cross-referencing. Especially on `author1`, but it does on `(year)`.

Comment: This works for single author works, but not if the last name has two parts (e.g. "van Pelt"). What would you do then?

Answer (score 13):

[A previous answer by Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22337/22603) provides a possessive citation command that works with older versions of Biblatex. However, this code does not work in Biblatex 3.3 due to [a change to the format of `\DeclareNameFormat`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299084/22603).

The following adaptation of Audrey's code (to which I am grateful to [PLK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1657/plk) for a slight correction) should work with Biblatex 3.3.  According to PLK, the `\nameparts` line isn't needed if you're using Biblatex 3.4.  (I'm not sure whether leaving it in will cause any problems.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname:poss}{% Based on labelname from biblatex.def
  \nameparts{#1}% Not needed if using Biblatex 3.4
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefixi}{\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}{'s}{}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}{#1's}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{#1}'s}
\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{#1's}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{shorthand}{shorthand:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{citetitle:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{label}{label:poss}}}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscite}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcite}
\newrobustcmd*{\Posscite}{\bibsentence\posscite}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscites}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcites}
```

Answer (score 6):

With the new name wrapper format introduced in `biblatex` v3.12 (2018-10-30), [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22337/35864) can be simplified quite a bit. We no longer need to redefine the whole `labelname` name format, we just append `'s` with the name wrapper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname:poss}{#1's}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}{#1's}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{#1}'s}

\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{#1's}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{shorthand}{shorthand:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{citetitle:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{label}{label:poss}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscite}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcite}

\newrobustcmd*{\Posscite}{\bibsentence\posscite}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscites}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcites}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bertram:sa,
  author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  shortauthor  = {BW},
  title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume       = {9},
  number       = {2},
  date         = {1996},
  pages        = {529--571},
}
@book{title,
  title = {A Book with No Author},
  date  = {1993},
}
@book{shorthand,
  title     = {A Book with No Author},
  shorthand = {ABWNA},
  date      = {1993},
}
@book{label,
  label = {Fallback label},
  date  = {1993},
}
@book{does,
  title       = {A Book by the Does},
  author      = {Doe, John and Doe, Jane},
  shortauthor = {{The Does}},
  date        = {1990},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{cite with labelname}
posscite many authors: \posscite[3036]{aksin}

textcite shortauthor: \textcite[e.g.][3]{bertram:sa}

posscite shortauthor: \posscite[e.g.][4]{bertram:sa}

textcite shorthand: \textcite{kant:ku}

posscite shorthand: \posscite{kant:ku}

textcite compact: \textcite{aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics}

posscite compact: \posscite{aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics}

textcites: \textcites[3036]{aksin}[529]{bertram:sa}

posscites: \posscites[3036]{aksin}[529]{bertram:sa}

posscite with plural labelname (where this solution is bad): \posscite{does}

\subsection*{cite without labelname}
textcite shorthand: \textcite{shorthand}

posscite shorthand: \posscite{shorthand}

textcite title: \textcite{title}

posscite title: \posscite{title}

textcite label: \textcite{label}

posscite label: \posscite{label}
\end{document}
```

[image: cite with labelname//posscite many authors: Aksın et al.’s (2006, p. 3036)//textcite shortauthor: BW (e.g. 1996, p. 3)//posscite shortauthor: BW’s (e.g. 1996, p. 4)//textcite shorthand: Kant (KU)//posscite shorthand: Kant’s (KU)//textcite compact: Aristotle (1929, 1968)//posscite compact: Aristotle’s (1929, 1968)//textcites: Aksın et al. (2006, p. 3036) and BW (1996, p. 529)//posscites: Aksın et al.’s (2006, p. 3036) and BW’s (1996, p. 529)//posscite with plural labelname (where this solution is bad): The Does’s//(1990)//cite without labelname//textcite shorthand: ABWNA//posscite shorthand: ABWNA’s//textcite title: A Book with No Author (1993)//posscite title: A Book with No Author’s (1993)//textcite label: Fallback label (1993)//posscite label: Fallback label’s (1993)]

Answer (score 0):

As a complement, here are the lines to add for a no-parentheses variant of \posscite (which is actually a possessive variant of \cite instead of \textcite).

```
            % Possessive Cite (no parentheses) \posscitenopar 
    
    \newrobustcmd*{\posscitenopar}{%
        \posscitealias%
        \cite}
    
    \newrobustcmd*{\Posscitenopar}{\bibsentence\posscite}
    
    \newrobustcmd*{\posscitesnopar}{%
        \posscitealias%
        \cites}
```