# biblatex: Tighter integration of \textcite "in the flow of text"

Tags: biblatex, citing

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)

Many `biblatex` citation styles feature the `\textcite` command which is *"intended for use in the flow of text, replacing the subject of a sentence"* (manual, section 3.6.2). At the moment, this works well for citations of single works -- e.g. (assuming the `authoryear` style), one may write in the source

```
The reference work is \textcite{knuth:ct:a}.
```

which will be typeset as

> The reference work is Knuth (1984).

Citing multiple works, on the other hand, is somewhat tedious. If one simply writes (1):

```
Important works are \textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,markey}.
```

the output is rather a list than a correct sentence (2):

> Important works are Knuth (1984); Knuth (1986); Markey (2005).

One has to write (3):

```
Important works are \textcite{knuth:ct:a}, \textcite{knuth:ct:b}, and \textcite{markey}.
```

to get (4):

> Important works are Knuth (1984), Knuth (1986), and Markey (2005).

Can `\textcite` be modified so that input (1) will yield output (4), hereby achieving a tighter integration "in the flow of text"?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

This is how \texttt{\textbackslash textcite} currently works:\\
Important works are \textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,markey}.

\bigskip

But I'd like \texttt{\textbackslash textcite} to output the following:\\
Important works are \textcite{knuth:ct:a}, \textcite{knuth:ct:b}, and \textcite{markey}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Upgrade to the the latest biblatex version. As of biblatex 2.7, this feature has been incorporated into all of the standard styles, including `authoryear` and its variants. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{\texttt{authoryear} and \texttt{\textbackslash textcite}}
%\subsection*{\texttt{authoryear-comp} and \texttt{\textbackslash textcite}}
\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b} \\
\textcite{knuth:ct:b,markey} \\
\textcite{bertram,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b} \\
\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,markey} \\
\textcite{markey,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,bertram}
\subsection*{\texttt{authoryear} and \texttt{\textbackslash textcites}}
%\subsection*{\texttt{authoryear-comp} and \texttt{\textbackslash textcites}}
\textcites(See)(for example){knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:b} \\
\textcites(See)(for example)[cf.][]{knuth:ct:b}[9--18]{markey} \\
\textcites[10--15]{knuth:ct:a}[cf.][]{knuth:ct:b}[9--18]{markey} \\
\textcites{bertram}{markey}{knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:b} \\
\textcites{companion}{knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:b} \\
\textcites{aristotle:poetics}{aristotle:rhetoric}{knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:b}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output with `authoryear` and `american` localization, which enables serial commas:

[image]

Here's the output with `authoryear-comp` and `american` localization:

[image]

Use of serial commas is not straightforward in nested lists, particularly in the verbose styles. Suggestions for improvements can be submitted to the [biblatex github repo](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Comment: This is great! If I may ask a follow-up-question: Can you also modify `\textcite` for the `authoryear-comp` style so that my original example would result in `Important works are Knuth (1984, 1986), and Markey (2005).`?

Comment: @lockstep I'll take a look. You know, that comma before "and" (`, and`) bothers me. Are you wanting the comma to handle the case where `maxcitenames` > 1` and the first citation is a two-author work? For example: `Smith and Doe (1998), and Markey (2005)`?

Comment: Yes, this is a great solution. I'll delete mine.

Comment: I think the comma before "and" is required in English for "enumerations" with at least three elements. On second thought, a) my example should read `Knuth (1984, 1986) and Markey (2005)` b) one  would need to differentiate between `\textcite` with two vs. with at least three works in its argument.

Comment: @lockstep So "elements" are (possibly compact) citations? In the multicite setting knowing the total number of citations from the outset can get tricky for cases like: `\textcites{<key1>}{<key2>,<key3>}`. Here `multicitetotal` is 2. In order of iteration `citetotal` is: 1, 2, 2.

Comment: Re: "elements" -- indeed. But I don't think that cases like `\textcites{<key1>}{<key2>,<key3>}` are of practical importance.

Comment: @lockstop Turns out that case isn't a problem. Getting the final delimiter right before a compact citation is tricky, though. I'll update this post to cover off the final delimiter issue in `authoryear`. But for `authoryear-comp`, I'll need to find some more spare time to take a closer look at it.

Comment: @Audrey: Accepted right now. I'm looking forward to an `authoryear-comp` solution, and your code should make it into the biblatex core.

Comment: @lockstep Getting the solution for `authoryear-comp` wasn't very difficult after all, thanks to Marco's feature request. My first update didn't handle `multipostnote`, but it does now. It will also handle the mix of qualified and unqualified citations lists we discussed earlier - I just neglected to include an example.

Comment: @Audrey: Is your answer to my question somehow part of Marco's feature request, or should I (or possibly you) add another feature request at `sourceforge.biblatex`?

Comment: @lockstep No, Marco's request won't cover this answer. It is very specific to the problem considered in [henrique's question on defining a `\textcite` command for verbose styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26401/4483). Another feature request is probably in order. I'd rather have it come from you, but if you insist I could post a request myself.

Comment: Just trying to clean up some feature requests - was this implemented does anyone know? I see this feature request, perhaps just a duplicate: https://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex/features/145/

Comment: @PLK No. I'll look at it within the next few months. This question is related to a more recent one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89625/4483

Comment: @Audrey Thanks again for looking into this. It would be great if this feature is implemented for all `authoryear` variants ("bare", `comp`, `ibid`, `icomp`) and possibly for the other style families as well.

Comment: @lockstep We've made progess on this issue [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/82). If you're interested in testing, pull the dev branch from the github repo and install with, say, `/build/build.sh install 2.7 ~/texmf/`. The resulting version requires the latest biber, but the updated `\textcite` output is backend-invariant.

Comment: @lockstep : does this also work with `\cites` (instead of `\textcites`)? It seems that it does not. What speaks against it? It would be nice to be able to have a footnote `\footnote{Cf. \cites[23]{key1}[99]{key2}[15]{key3}}` rendered as `Cf. Author1, work1, pp. 23; Author2, work2, pp. 99; **and** Author3, work3, pp. 15.` -- Using `\footcites` here creates a reference including brackets wich is not suitable for footnotes. (Using `authortitle-comp`)

Comment: @lockstep : (and the same question applies to `\footcites[23]{key1}[99]{key2}[15]{key3}` as well.)

Comment: @ClintEastwood The new feature applies only to commands based on `\textcite` because its output forms part of a sentence. Other citation commands are generally parenthetical. Most style guides delimit parenthetical citation lists with semicolons.

Comment: @math It is possible, but you wouldn't re-define `\textcite` that way - probably something like `\AtNextCite{<swap and string with or string>}\textcite`. This comment trail is long enough, so please ask a new question.