# How to get an "and" before the last element in BibLaTeX's textcite commands?

Tags: biblatex, citing

When using `\textcite` or `\textcites` with more than one author in BibLaTeX, the result is not really usable and has to be fixed manually which can hardly be the point of the command:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{alice,
  author = {Alice, A.},
}
@book{bob,
  author = {Bob, B.},
}
@collection{charlie,
  editor = {Charlie, C.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sortcites]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Refer to the works of \textcite{charlie,alice,bob}.

Refer to the works of \textcite{alice,bob} and \textcite{charlie}.
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Alice, Bob, Charlie vs. Alice, Bob and Charlie]

One can argue about having a comma between the second and third element but surely the "and" is mandatory in English. So is there a way to get BibLaTeX to behave that way?

Comment: For the comma issue, have a look at the `\finalandcomma` macro in the biblatex manual which is especially for this.

Comment: @PLK the manual states that this is for `\finalnamedelim` which sounds good but is just used for multiple names in one citation and not for multiple citations. Irritatingly so, I should add.

Comment: Good point. We will look at this for biblatex 2.6 I think since 2.5 is likely to be released this month.

Comment: @PLK that's great to hear :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Biblatex offers the counters `citecount` and `citetotal`. `citetotal` holds the total number of valid entry keys passed to the citation command, and `citecount` is the counter of the citation being processed.  Thus we can use such counter to identify whether a citation is the last on in a list of citations. The standard  definition of `\textcite` makes use of the  macro `textcite` where the delimiter is inserted after the current entry. We can thus include a check to identify whether we are processing the second last entry, and to print  an "and" instead of the delimiter.

Here is the modified version of the `textcite` biblatex macro

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}-1}
    {\gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace}}%
    {\gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}}%
}  
\makeatother
```

It produces:

[image]

Comment: Great, works perfectly, even for contracted entries due to duplicate authors :)

Comment: Any suggestions for natbib + bibtex?

Comment: @Christian Not quite perfectly; the final delimiter is incorrect when the last two (or more) citation labels are compressed. To fix this just upgrade to biblatex 2.7.

Comment: @Audrey Great to see this in `biblatex` now :) Just did an upgrade.