# Change last multicite delim only for \textcite commands (not in bibliography)

Tags: biblatex, delimiters

Using biblatex with the authoryear-comp style you can set the 'and' sign for multiple authors by the **\DefineBibliographyStrings** command.

Is it possible to define a different **'and'** sign for intext multiple citations only?

For example a multicite in the text **\textcite(AF01, BB10,CF11)** should appear like:
A. Foo et al. (2001), B. Bar et al. (2010) **and** C. Foo et al. (2011).

However, in the bibliography another 'and' sign should be used for citations with multiple authors:

A. Foo et al. (2001) - A. Foo, A. Rock **&** A. Bar: "Mytitle ..." (2001)

B. Bar et al. (2010) - B. Bar, B. Pop **&** B.Bar: "Mytitle 2..." (2010)

....

I tried  (without success):
[Separation between last and secondlast item in citet with authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111926/separation-between-last-and-secondlast-item-in-citet-with-authoryear-style)

Any help is appreciated,
Harry

Comment: Do you maybe just want `\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}`?

Comment: Please consider creating an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we have something to play around with and can make sure that it actually works with your set-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separator between the second-to-last and last name is `\finalnamedelim`, so we can just change that

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxbibnames=999, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\begin{document}
\textcite{aksin,knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

If you want to change the delimiter between the second-to-last and last `\textcite` you need to change `\textcitedelim`. Its standard definition from `biblatex.def` is

```
\newcommand*{\textcitedelim}{%
  \iffinalcitedelim
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{2}
       {\iftextcitepunct{\finalandsemicolon}{\finalandcomma}}{}%
     \addspace\bibstring{and}}
    {\iftextcitepunct{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma}}%
  \space}
```