# Different `andothers` expressions for `\textcite` and `\parencite`

Tags: macros, biblatex

Is it possible to have two different expressions for `andothers`, when using either in-text or parentheses citation with `biblatex` classes?

For instance, I would like to use "and others" in text (with `\textcite`) and "et al." in parentheses (with `\parencite`). Like so:

> As presented by Yoon and others (2006), ...
>
> This has been previously presented (Yoon et al., 2006) ...

It says in the manual (p. 103):

> `\textcitedelim`
>
> Similar to `\multicitedelim`, but used by `\textcite` and related commands
>   (§ 3.7.2). The default is a comma plus an interword space. The standard styles modify
>   this provisional definition to ensure that the delimiter before the final citation is the
>   localized term ‘and’, separated by interword spaces.

But I wasn't sure which styles were those or how they modify it.

I consulted questions and answers like [Change last multicite delim only for textcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280617/change-last-multicite-delim-only-for-textcite-commands-not-in-bibliography) (only contrasting it to bibliography entries) and [Switch conjunction in textcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162461/how-to-switch-conjunction-from-and-to-or-when-using-many-bibkeys-in-textcite), but couldn't make their solutions work for my needs.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example. This can't be answered as it stands as far as I know as the information provided is too deficient.

Comment: Note that `\textcitedelim` is the separator between multiple citations (for example in `\textcite{foo,bar}`) and has nothing to do with the `andothers` bibstring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with version 3.4 of `biblatex` there is the concept of `delimcontext`s that are used to find out in what context (`\parencite`, `\textcite`, bibliography, text is printed), we can use that to determine of we are in a `\textcite`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifintextcite{\ifdefstring{\blx@delimcontext}{textcite}}
\makeatother
```

There is no need for patching the commands and a new toggle here.

We can then modify the `andothers` bibstring depending on that test

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {\ifintextcite{and others}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifintextcite{\ifdefstring{\blx@delimcontext}{textcite}}
\makeatother

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {\ifintextcite{and others}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
}


\begin{document}
   \textcite{aksin} \parencite{aksin}

   \printbibliography   
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's smart, utilizing the new internal `biblatex` checks. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In the standard `authoryear` biblatex style, both `\parencite` and `\textcite` internally is use the `name:others` bibmacro. What we can do is to create a toggle that is switched on and off try `\textcite`, and we use the toggle for a conditional to be used inside the macro that prints the "and others" or "et al" strings.

```
\newtoggle{myintextcite}
```

The simplest way is to use the `xpatch` package and to prepend the command to switch the toggle on, and append the command to switch it off.

```
\xpretobibmacro{textcite}{\toggletrue{myintextcite}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{textcite}{\togglefalse{myintextcite}}{}{}
```

Given that we have already loaded `xpatch`, we can use it to patch the `name:andothers` bibmacro

```
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}
  {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
  {\andothersdelim\iftoggle{myintextcite}{and others}{\bibstring{andothers}}}
  {}
  {}
```

Notice that (1) the `andothers` string prints "et. al." and (2) there is no `etal` string.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Giudo! I couldn't get this to work with apa-style and a language mapping, so I updated my `biblatex` and used the [solution suggested by moewe](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309547/66629).