# How to switch conjunction from "and" to "or" when using many bibkeys in textcite?

Tags: biblatex

With biblatex is very convenient to write something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\ldots as presented by \textcite{shore,yoon,cicero}
\end{document}
```

Then biblatex will automatically render this to:

> ...as presented by Shore [2], Yoon et al. [3], and Cicero [1]

Sometime it would be helpful to not use **and** as conjunction but **or**. Is that possible?

BTW: Why is there no comma when there are only two items in \textcite{foo,bar}? When there are two authors and maxcitenames=2 this is rendered to:

> "..as presented by Foo and Bar [1] and Bar and Foo [2]"

**Possible duplicates:**

This question is related to [biblatex: Tighter integration of \textcite "in the flow of text"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28461), where this question was actually a comment, but as the comment trail was too long already I was asked to make a new question, so here it is.

Also the question might seem related to [Change citation conjunction from "and" to "i"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109221/change-citation-conjunction-from-and-to-i) but this is asking for different conjunctions within a single bibkey connecting authors.

Comment: Can you give an actual example in which *or* is more suited than *and*? I can't think of any...

Comment: In response to your BTW: the Oxford comma applies ONLY in a series of three or more terms.

Comment: @Jubobs, I want to make it more clear that the literture list not complete with "or". When using "and" it sounds more like a complete list.

Comment: @math I understand, but using "or" is dangerous because it can be misinterpreted as an exclusive "or". If you really want to convey the fact that the list of references is not exhaustive, you could write *as presented by Shore [2], Yoon et al. [3], and Cicero [1], among others*, or something like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make use of `biblatex`'s localisation capabilities we can define a new bibliography string `or`.

```
\NewBibliographyString{or}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  or = {or},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  or = {oder},
}
```

We can then define a new command that will change the "and" in `\textcite` to an "or".

```
\newcommand{\useor}{%
  \renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{%
    \iffinalcitedelim
      {\ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{2}
       {\iftextcitepunct{\finalandsemicolon}{\finalandcomma}}{}%
      \addspace\bibstring{or}}% here was \bibstring{and} before
      {\iftextcitepunct{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma}}%
    \space}%
}
```

The `\textcite` commands can then very easily be patched to use "or" instead of "and" by adding `\useor` to the wrapper command.

For `numeric` and friends that would be

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textciteor}[\useor\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\makeatother
```

For `authortitle`/`authoryear` you would use

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textciteor}[\useor]
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

Look up the `\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}` in your `.cbx` file, copy the definition, change the name to `\textciteor` and add `\useor` to the wrapper command (that is the portion in square brackets just after `\DeclareCiteCommand{\textciteor}`, create this optional argument if its not there already).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{or}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  or = {or},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  or = {oder},
}

\newcommand{\useor}{%
  \renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{%
    \iffinalcitedelim
      {\ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{2}
       {\iftextcitepunct{\finalandsemicolon}{\finalandcomma}}{}%
      \addspace\bibstring{or}}
      {\iftextcitepunct{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma}}%
    \space}%
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textciteor}[\useor\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ldots as presented by \textcite{shore,yoon,cicero,baez/article}.

\ldots as presented by \textciteor{shore,yoon,cicero,baez/article}.

Just to test \textcite{shore,yoon,cicero,baez/article}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Of course you can also hook `\useor` into `\AtNextCite`:

```
Just to test \textcite{shore,yoon,cicero,baez/article}.
Just to test \AtNextCite{\useor}\textcite{shore,yoon,cicero,baez/article}.
Just to test \textcite{shore,yoon,cicero,baez/article}.
```

And then define

```
\newrobustcmd*{\textciteor}{\AtNextCite{\useor}\textcite}
```

thanks to @Audrey for that solution.

---

Regarding your BTW: `biblatex` only uses the Oxford/serial comma for list with more than two items.

The standard definitions are:

```
\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\newcommand*{\finallistdelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\newcommand*{\textcitedelim}{%
  \iffinalcitedelim
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{2}
       {\iftextcitepunct{\finalandsemicolon}{\finalandcomma}}{}%
     \addspace\bibstring{and}}
    {\iftextcitepunct{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma}}%
  \space}
```

One can of course force the `\finalandcomma` to appear always by

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

and the like.

Comment: Pretty sure the Oxford comma goes with “or” just as much as “and.”

Comment: @LukeMaurer I suppose you are right, I deleted the passage, as it was probably more confusing than helpful anyway.

Comment: @moewe Just go with `\newrobustcmd*{\textciteor}{\AtNextCite{\useor}\textcite}`. BTW: Thanks a bunch for your posts here.

Answer (score 6):

You can define a new cite command `\textciteor` that does that.

The following code is required in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textciteor}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textciteor}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textciteor}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textciteor]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\newbibmacro*{textciteor}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textciteordelim}}
\newcommand*{\textciteordelim}{%
  \iffinalcitedelim
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{2}
       {\iftextcitepunct{\finalandsemicolon}{\finalandcomma}}{}%
     \addspace or}
    {\iftextcitepunct{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma}}%
  \space}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textciteor}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textciteor}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textciteor}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textciteor]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\newbibmacro*{textciteor}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textciteordelim}}
\newcommand*{\textciteordelim}{%
  \iffinalcitedelim
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{2}
       {\iftextcitepunct{\finalandsemicolon}{\finalandcomma}}{}%
     \addspace or}
    {\iftextcitepunct{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma}}%
  \space}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ldots as presented by \textcite{shore,yoon,cicero}

\ldots as presented by \textciteor{shore,yoon,cicero}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]