# Biblatex: First citation as full reference and following citations ibid or - when interrupted - short author-year citation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

For my thesis I would like to have a citation style that meet the following requirements.

a) Whenever a bibliography entry is cited the first time it will generate the full entry (author, year, title etc.).

b) When it is used again without other entries in between it will be shown as "ibid." and page number if it is different.

c) When it is used again later on and other entries are in between, it should generate surname and year.

**Example**: Entries like this

```
\autocite[48]{hG89}
\autocite[48]{hG89}
\autocite[50]{hG89}
\autocite[34]{yH11}
\autocite[46]{hG89}
```

should lead to footnotes like this

1. Grice, Herbert P. (1975) ≫Logic and Conversation≪. In: Syntax and semantics, S. 48.
2. Ibid.
3. Ibid., S. 50.
4. Huang, Yan (2011): Pragmatics. Oxford [u. a.]: Oxford University Press, S. 34.
5. Grice (1975), S. 46.

Is there a way to generate this in `biblatex`?

Comment: See the [**authoryear-ibib**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/authoryear-ibid) and the [**authoryear-icomp**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/authoryear-ibid) styles.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, henrique. Both styles meet the requirements b) and c) perfectly, but they appear not to generate a complete entry when a reference is first cited. Do I miss something?

Comment: Indeed. What you need is something that behaves like `verbose-ibib` as suggested by Bernard, but that falls back to `authoryear-ibid`. I think you should look in both `.cbx` files to see how they define the `cite` bibmacro.

Comment: I took a look at both .cbx files. Unfortunatelly, I didn´t get anything.

Comment: See also [BibLaTeX: Making verbose-authoryear fullbibliography at once](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32354/35864).

Answer (score 13):

Using `\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber]{biblatex}` gives you almost what you want, except that by default it will give author-title short citations while you prefer author-year. Fortunately this can be changed quite quickly.

First, we ask `biblatex` to provide `labeldate` for us, this is important for year disambiguations. We just add `labeldateparts` to the package options and call `biblatex` with

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, labeldateparts]{biblatex}
```

Secondly, we redefine the short citations command `cite:short` to give us author-year; we also set the name output to always use `family-given`.

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}}
```

And that's it.

By default, `verbose-ibid` loads the bibliography style `authortitle`.
Seeing that you have short author-year citations and not author-title ones, it might be a good idea to make `biblatex` use the `authoryear` instead of the `authortitle` bibliography style; so load `biblatex` with `citestyle=verbose-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear` instead of `style=verbose-ibid`.

```
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear, backend=biber, labeldateparts]{biblatex}
```

A short example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear, backend=biber, labeldateparts]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mvcollection{syasem,
  title     = {Syntax and Semantics},
  location  = {New York},
  publisher = {Academic Press},
}
@collection{SpeActs,
  title     = {Speech Acts},
  volume    = {3},
  editor    = {Peter Cole and Jerry L. Morgan},
  date      = {1975},
  crossref  = {syasem},
}
@incollection{grice,
  author    = {Grice, Herbert Paul},
  title     = {Logic and Conversation},
  pages     = {41-58},
  crossref  = {SpeActs},
}
@book{huang,
  author    = {Yan Huang},
  title     = {Pragmatics},
  date      = {2011},
  series    = {Oxford Textbooks in Linguistics},
  isbn      = {978-0-19-924368-6},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  location  = {Oxford and others},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}}

\begin{document}
  Cite\footcite{cicero} this\footcite{wilde}, now\footcite{wilde} again\footcite{cicero}.
  Yep\footcite[1]{knuth:ct:b} now this\footcite[2]{knuth:ct:c} again: Go\footcite[3]{knuth:ct:b} and\footcite[4]{knuth:ct:c}.
  Let's\footcite{baez/article} cite\footcite{grice} an\footcite{grice} article\footcite{huang}, now\footcite{grice} this\footcite{grice}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, moewe. Before I can use it, I have to figure out, how to get biber in my biblatex running.

Comment: @Philip With a fairly up-to-date LaTeX distribution that should be not too hard at all. The answer should work without Biber as well, just replace `backebd=biber` by `backend=bibtex`. Note though that with BibTeX the `crossref` field will not be treated as expected, so the example entry `grice` will look slightly off.

Answer (score 2):

I obtained this with the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,citetracker]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Bernard. The verbose-ibid style meet the requirements a) and b), but when I use it again after another reference was cited, it generates a surname-title footnote instead of a surname-year footnote, so c) is not met. Could this be solved anyhow?