# BibLatex verbose-ibid full cite after every change of reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, footnotes

Is it possible to always cite the full source after changing the reference, instead of using the shorted version with *last-name, title* verbose-ibid offers? I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139158/biblatex-first-citation-as-full-reference-and-following-citations-ibid-or-whe) question by someone else. It seems to be possible to rewrite `cite:short` using `\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}` if that helps. Is it possible to just replace `cite:short` with `cite:long/full` or however it might be called?

My current setup: `\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-ibid,natbib=true,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}`

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-ibid,natbib=true,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key2,
    author = {Author, B.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Title 2},
    publisher = {Publisher 2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \footcite{key1}, consectetur adipiscing elit \footcite{key1}, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \footcite{key2}. Ut enim ad minim veniam \footcite{key2}, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat \footcite{key1}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I basicly want, that footnote 5 is "A. Author (2001). Title. Publisher." instead of "Author, Title."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You'd like "ibid" to work though? What about shorthands? Also, please consider adding a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `cite` bibmacro to use `cite:full` instead of `cite:short`:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifboolexpr{
          test {\ifciteibid}
          and
          not test {\iffirstonpage}
        }
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
```

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-ibid,natbib=true,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key2,
    author = {Author, B.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Title 2},
    publisher = {Publisher 2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifboolexpr{
          test {\ifciteibid}
          and
          not test {\iffirstonpage}
        }
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \footcite{key1}, consectetur adipiscing elit \footcite{key1}, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \footcite{key2}. Ut enim ad minim veniam \footcite{key2}, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat \footcite{key1}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1) Slightly shorter: `\letbibmacro{cite:short}{cite:full}` makes `cite:short` always execute the same code as `cite:full` leading to the same result.

Comment: @moewe "slightly" :)  Didn't think of that, and it's actually a very nice idea. I'd say it deserves an answer of it's own. Please feel free.

Comment: I don't think you should have deleted your answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419705/35864 to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419702/35864. It was a perfectly good and clever idea.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\letbibmacro{cite:short}{cite:full}
```

we can `\let` the bibmacro `cite:short` execute what `cite:full` would do. This uses `\let`, so it copies the definition of `cite:full` when the `\letbibmacro` is executed. See [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258/35864)

If you'd rather have the definition of `cite:full` at the time of executing `cite:short`, i.e. handle the assignment with `\def`, use

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{\usebibmacro{cite:full}}
```

instead.