# How to make a customized latex bibliography

Tags: citing, overleaf, bibliographystyle

I'm struggling to make costum made bibliography style

[image]

with a certain citationstyle in Overleaf/latex
For Books: Last name, First name: Title. Subtitle. Edition. Place of publication: Publisher, Year (=Series).

For Articles in Journals/Edited Volumes: Last name, First name: "Title. Subtitle". In: Last name, First name (Hrsg.): Title. Subtitle.
Edition. Place of publication: Publisher, Year (=Series), Page number.

[image]

**UPDATE**
I almost got it. But I still struggle with the correct Format. In my first try, the footnotes are almost correct. The fifth footnote needs to be formatted as follow "Vgl. : , ". And the there are weird linebrakes. However, the bibliography looks off...

```
    \usepackage[
backend=biber,
citestyle=verbose-ibid,
sorting=ynt,
%style=ext-authoryear,
bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
backend=biber, 
introcite=label, 
dashed=false
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}}
```

[image]

If I use `style=ext-authoryear` the bibliography looks fine, but my footnotes are all gone.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. First, if you haven't done this before, I would suggest trying to see if someone else has already coded the style you are looking for. Is the style specified by a particular publisher / academic society? Do you have a link to the details of what the style requires? Maybe someone can point you to the right track with that information. Secondly, you showed both footnotes and endnotes, which feels a bit redundant, what are the rules for that? Thirdly, are you using something like bib(la)tex? Or are you typing entries by hand in `thebibliography`?

Comment: For `bibtex`, you can generate new bibliography styles using https://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib . For `biblatex`, writing one's own `bbx` file is not too hard (nor too easy). It may be easier to start with an existing one and modify. See e.g. the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139158/biblatex-first-citation-as-full-reference-and-following-citations-ibid-or-whe

Comment: 1. I have already asked my university, but they did not provide me a latex-template.
The text was originally written in microsoft word, however i did struggle mit korean and chinese charactes and the formatation. So i switched to overleaf.
The bibliography is handwritten in word.

2. It's the german citation style. The fotenotes and bibliograph adhere the same rules as mentioned above

The only difference is for format of the bibliography style.

3. typing by hands with `thebibliography` would also be fine if i can get it formatted as in the first picture.