# Citations as nouns in biblatex-Chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm trying to get started with biblatex-chicago, and have got stuck on how to refer to citations as nouns in the footnote style (that is, I want to say 'as \citeasnoun{lamport} says...').

[I *think* the short version of this question is: "why doesn't my `\smartcite` expand to `\parencite` in a footnote?"]

If I start off as the biblatex-chicago manual suggests

```
\usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex-chicago}
```

then everything's fine: I can use `\textcite{foo}` as a noun, and `\autocite{foo}` parenthetically.  If, however, I start off with the manual's suggested alternative

```
\usepackage[notes,strict,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex-chicago}
```

then I don't have `\textcite` (that's slightly surprising, since the biblatex manual says that '[`\textcite`] commands are provided by all non-verbose styles which ship with this package,' and I would have guessed that the 'notes' style was a 'non-verbose' style).

That's OK, since I can apparently fake it with `\def\textcite#1{\citeauthor{#1}\autocite{#1}}`.  That almost works: in the text I get 'as Lamport^1 says ...', and a reasonable footnote with the full reference.

If, however, I try this within a footnote, I get 'as LamportLeslie Lamport ... says ...' -- that is, the `\autocite` appears to act like plain `\cite` in a footnote, whereas I would have expected something more like 'as Lamport (Leslie Lamport ...) says ...'.

Things I've tried:

- I can specify `autocite=footnote` and `autocite=inline` in the `\usepackage` command, but that changes it in both contexts -- the body text and the footnotes.
- I could potentially look in the `biblatex.sty` for clues, and hack up something which is somehow sensitive to its context so that `\autocite` acts like `\parencite` in a footnote, but (a) that style is ... quite clever in places, and (b) I'm doing this on behalf of someone else, so a partial goal is to say 'look, LaTeX can do this more easily than doing it by hand' -- an argument which 'use the source, Luke' would rather undermine.  And anyway (c) I thought this was supposed to happen automatically.
- `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand` looks like it could help, but doesn't have the footnote/bodytext alternative I'd have expected.
- Replacing `\autocite` with `\smartcite` effects no change, even though `\smartcite` is '[l]ike \parencite in a footnote and like \footcite in the body,' according to the biblatex manual (`\parencite` by itself does produce a citation in parentheses).

I've been through the manual enough times now that I believe I'm missing something obvious, or else I'm asking the wrong question.

- Perhaps the answer is to use `\parencite` explicitly in footnotes.  Perhaps, but I rather got the impression that that was what `\autocite` was supposed to take care of.
- Perhaps the answer is that I shouldn't want to do this.  I'm not in the Humanities, so perhaps Everyone Knows (except me) that one simply doesn't refer to references like this, in footnotes.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\iftrue
  \usepackage[notes,strict,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex-chicago}
  \def\textcite#1{\citeauthor{#1}\smartcite{#1}}
\else
  \usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex-chicago}
\fi
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\title{Document}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The primary aim of this essay is to refer to \textcite{wittgenstein53}
in the text.\footnote{And refer to \textcite{wittgenstein53} in a footnote}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get "Wittgenstein^1" in the first case, and "Wittgensteinibid." in the footnote.

I'm using biblatex version 1.7, biber version 0.9.9 (and up-to-date versions of pdftex and xetex).

Comment: Up to date means: biblatex 2.2 and biber 1.2 ;-)

Comment: Hrmph: I was using the versions in TeXLive 2012. But you're right -- I see biblatex 2.2 is available.  So tlmgr updates me to biblatex-chicago 2.0, biblatex 2.2 and biber 1.2, but unfortunately I see exactly the same behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Style-related content in the `biblatex` manual doesn't necessarily apply to contributed styles. One example is `biblatex-chicago`'s `\smartcite` command. It doesn't generate parenthetical citations.

The `notes` style is verbose; you get full citation labels on the first citation. Version 1.7 of `biblatex` introduced `\textcite` and friends to all its verbose styles. To incorporate similar commands into `biblatex-chicago` you can adapt definitions from `verbose.cbx`.

```
\makeatletter

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite\cbx@textcite@i]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}}
  {\printnames{labelname}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}}
  {\multinamedelim}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}[\cbx@textcite\cbx@textcites@i]
  {\textcite}{\multinamedelim}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@textcite}[2]{\def\cbx@savedcites{#1}#2\cbx@savedcites}
\newrobustcmd{\cbx@textcite@i}{\iffootnote{\addspace\parencite}{\footcite}}
\newrobustcmd{\cbx@textcites@i}{\iffootnote{\addspace\parencites}{\footcites}}

\makeatother
```

Here citation command arguments are processed twice. The first pass generates output like `\citeauthor`. The second pass generates a footnote or parenthetical citation. I've tailored the code to handle citations inside footnotes and work with `\parencite`, `\footcite` and friends from `notes`.

The resulting commands don't move punctuation for you. To incorporate this feature into `\textcite`, you can use a [low-level definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26418).

Comment: thanks, this works for me. One meta-question:  would be regarded as an omission in biblatex-chicago? Or put another way, ought I not to want this -- am I misusing the style by wanting `\textcite` in these contexts? (like I say, I'm not myself familiar with the Chicago style, and haven't read that manual).

Comment: @NormanGray Since the standard verbose styles have a `\textcite` command, I'd consider it an omission. You could try contacting the `biblatex-chicago` author to request this feature.

Comment: @NormanGray No problem. Feel free to update my answer if the author ends up adding citation commands for you - I don't follow the development of this package too closely. I'll correct the `biblatex` manual re: `\textcite` and verbose styles.