# Using a citation as a noun in conjunction with cite.sty

Tags: citing, ieeetran, cite-package

I need to use IEEEtran document class, which uses the cite package to create numbered citations. However, I want to use citations as nouns, which is not supported by cite. Hardcoding author names seems error-prone.

Is there a standalone package which provides functionality similar to BibLaTeX's \textcite, which does not clash with cite.sty?

Specifically, I want to type something like

```
\textcite{exampleauthor} \cite{exampleauthor} said ``Don't use a citation as a noun.''
```

and see something akin to:

```
Author et al. [7] said "Don't use a citation as a noun."
```

I had a look at [this description of how to do it in Chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67837/citations-as-nouns-in-biblatex-chicago), but I'm afraid I don't understand it sufficiently - pasting it in resulted in an error.

Ps. A discussion about the advisability of using citations as nouns is out of scope. This concerns a table where multiple studies are described.

**Edit: As requested, a minimal working example:**

```
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@article{test,
    author={A. Uthor},
    title = {A neat paper},
    journal = {Some random Journal},
    year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
{\textbf{Paper}} & {\textbf{Year}} & {\textbf{Findings}}\\
Uthor \cite{test} & 2013 & A tiny example paper describing citations.\\
% ^ Should not be hardcoded
\end{tabular}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{example.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

As noted, the use of IEEEtrans and cite, which goes with the document style, are fixed by external authority. Otherwise I would simply use a different citation package.

Comment: Did you try \citet() ?

Comment: Another way you can use natbib. By including \usepackage[autoryear]{natbib}. And in the text you cite using \citep{}. You can still use \cite fir numbered style.

Comment: Yes, I tried \citet, which gives "Undefined control sequence." It is not supplied as part of the cite package.

Because I am using an existing, complicated class (IEEETrans), I do not want to switch the citation package to natbib and risk breaking something.

That's why I am looking for a simple add-on to give me the functionality I need, which won't clash with any existing packages.

Comment: can you provide a working example so we can help you better ?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include an example. Thanks!