# multiple authors (names) of \textcites as possessive

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

Extending the earlier answers at [Author name of \textcite as possessive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22273/author-name-of-textcite-as-possessive), I wonder how to adapt the suggested code so that IF the second last cited entries' author field contains multiple names, the subsequent "and" (to deliminate the different entries) is substituted "beautifully" with an, e.g., "as well as".

```
\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
    @book{texbook,
    author  = {Donald E. Knuth and Someone Else},
    title   = {The {{\TeX}book}},
    publisher   = {Addison-Wesley},
    date    = {1984}
    }

    @inproceedings{foo,
      author = {Foo Bar and {Yet Another} Person},
      title = {Some article},
      abstract = {Here is the abstract.},
      crossref = {acl2015},
      year = {2015}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
```

and in the tex file I would want to use

```
\posscites{foo}{texbook}
```

and that should be printed as

```
 Knuth and Else's (1984) as well as Bar and Person's (2015)
```

A not quite minimal MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,safeinputenc,strict,pagetracker= true,loccittracker=constrict,citetracker=true,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,isbn=false,uniquelist=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents,iflang}

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22273/author-name-of-textcite-as-possessive
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname:poss}{% Based on labelname from biblatex.def
\nameparts{#1}% Not needed if using Biblatex 3.4
\ifcase\value{uniquename}%
\usebibmacro{name:family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}        {\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}%
\or
\ifuseprefix
{\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}    {\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffixi}}
{\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}    {\namepartprefixi}{\namepartsuffixi}}%
\or
\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}    {\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}%
\fi
\usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{%true:German language
    \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}{s}{}%
}{%false:nonGerman language
    \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}{'s}{}%
}
}%
\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{%true:German language
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{%
    \ifnameundef{labelname}{#1s}{#1}%
}%
}{%false:nonGerman language
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{%
    \ifnameundef{labelname}{#1's}{#1}%
}%
}%
\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{%true:German language
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{#1}s}
\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{#1s}%
}{%false:nonGerman language
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{#1}s}
\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{#1's}%
}%
\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
\AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{shorthand}{shorthand:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{citetitle:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{label}{label:poss}}}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscite}{%
\posscitealias%
\textcite}
\newrobustcmd*{\Posscite}{\bibsentence\posscite}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscites}{%
\posscitealias%
\textcites}




\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{bertram:sa,
  author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume = {9},
  number = {2},
  date = {1996},
  pages = {529--571}}
@Article{bertram:i,
    author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard and Brianny Winner},
    title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces imagined elsewhere},
    journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
    volume = {9},
    number = {2},
    date = {2088},
    pages = {529--571},
    note= {unpublished}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{british}
\subsection*{cases british}
1 posscite single item with several authors: \posscites[30]{aksin} \\

2 posscite multiple items: \posscites[e.g.][4]{bertram:sa}{aristotle:poetics} \\

3 posscite multiple items including final item with many authors:     \posscites[e.g.][4]{bertram:sa}{aristotle:poetics}[55]{bertram:i} \\
\end{otherlanguage} 

I would like the final case, #, to result in:
Bertram and Wentworth’s (e.g. 1996, 4), Aristotle’s (1968) \textbf{as well as} Bertram, Wentworth and Winner’s (2088, 55).  

That is, for the case of british english.

\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
    \subsection*{cases negerman}
    1 posscite single item with several authors: this would be another question \\

    2 posscite multiple items: \posscites[z.B.][4]{bertram:sa}    {aristotle:poetics} \\

    3 posscite multiple items including final item with many authors: \posscites[z.B.][4]{bertram:sa}{aristotle:poetics}[55]{bertram:i} \\
\end{otherlanguage} 

I would like the final case, 3, to result in: Bertram und Wentworths (z.B. 1996, 4), Aristotles (1968) \textbf{sowie} Bertram, Wentworth und Winners (2088, 55)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is add an `aswellas` bibliography string (with definitions) then change the definition of `\textcitedelim` to use `aswellas` instead of `and` for the delimiter before the final citation if the final citation has more than one name in it.

Add this to the preamble of your MWE above:

```
\NewBibliographyString{aswellas}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  aswellas = {as well as}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  aswellas = {sowei}
}
\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{%
  \iffinalcitedelim
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{2}
       {\iftextcitepunct{\finalandsemicolon}{\finalandcomma}}{}%
     \addspace
     \ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{1}
       {\bibstring{aswellas}}
       {\bibstring{and}}}
    {\iftextcitepunct{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma}}%
  \space}
```