# How to obtain “author’s (Axiom x, p. 22, year)” with a clickable year?

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following MWE, with this `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,sorting=ynt,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=99,hyperref=true,sortcites=true,language=british,backref=true,url=false,doi=false]{biblatex} % To get fancy bibliography.

% HYPERREF SETTINGS

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=blue}

% REDEFINING CITEYEAR

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
 {}
 {\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}}
 {\multicitedelim}
 {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
 {}
 {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}}}
 {\multicitedelim}
 {}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{author_yy}'s \citeyearpar[Axiom X, p. y]{author_yy}. 

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

And this `.bib` file:

```
@article{author_yy,
    title = {title},
    author = {author},
    journal = {journal},
    volume = {1},
    number = {1},
    pages = {yyy--xxx},
    year = {2000},
    doi = {XXXXXXXXXX}
}
```

As you can see in the output below, the bit `[Axiom X, p. y]` is lost due to my redefinitions of `\citeyear` and `\citeyearpar`. My goal is to get a clickable year while keeping the bit `[Axiom X, p. y]` in the output. Can you help me achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22273/35864 (the accepted answer is outdated, though, check the other answers as well).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried the MWE in your answer and it works. But unfortunately, I must be doing something in my preamble that prevents your solution from working in my actual document. So, I am still where I was…

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be much easier than anticipated. Just use:

`\citeauthor{author_yy}’s (Axiom X, p. y, \citeyear{author_yy})`

That will do.

Comment: The problem with `\citeyear` is that is just shows the year. If you need `extradate`, because you have two works by the same authors from the same year, the letter is not shown. Try citing both `knuth:ct:b` and `knuth:ct:c` from `biblatex-examples.bib`.