# Why does using IfEndWith inside DeclareNameWrapperFormat throw an error?

Tags: biblatex, xstring

I wanted to use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591114/238079) solution for having possessive citations in BibLaTeX, but extend it to account correctly for names ending in 's' (at least in english). The solution posted in that question *does not* account for these, but *does* compile fine on my machine.

I thought that I could extend it easily enough by just using `xstring` to check whether the name ended with 's', and if did then only adding `'` to the end, rather than `'s`. I tried the below mwe, but I got a compilation error:

### error

```
ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \xs_arg_i.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
=
l.51 \posscite{crane22_plural} 
                             is the easy case.
```

MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\author{ModallyFragile}
\title{Foo}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Support possessive citation
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname:poss}{\IfEndWith{#1}{s}{#1'}{#1's}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{\ifnameundef{labelname}{\IfEndWith{#1}{s}{#1'}{#1's}}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{\IfEndWith{#1}{s}{#1'}{#1's}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{\IfEndWith{#1}{s}{#1'}{#1's}}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{shorthand}{shorthand:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{citetitle:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{label}{label:poss}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscite}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcite}

\newrobustcmd*{\Posscite}{\bibsentence\posscite}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscites}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcites}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{crane22_plural,
    date = {2022},
    title = {Plurals are easy!},
    author = {Crane, Tim},
    timestamp = {2023-07-23 20:44:43 (BST)}
}

@Article{mills23_plural,
    date = {2023},
    title = {Plurals are hard},
    author = {Mills, Charles W.},
    timestamp = {2023-07-23 20:44:18 (BST)}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\posscite{crane22_plural} is the easy case.

But \posscite{mills23_plural} is the hard case.

\end{document}
```

I've isolated the error to my use of `IfEndWith` inside `DeclareNameWrapperFormat`.

What is causing this (and how can I stop it happening)?

Comment: Sorry, but your argument `#1` contains the instructions to print the family name, not the family name itself and these instructions are not fully expandable. This will lead to low level errors, as you found out. There is no reference to the answer you tried to modify, can you please add it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to actually include the link. Now fixed.