# harvard - modify \possessivecite

Tags: bibliographies, citing, harvard-style

I am writing reports in norwegian, and I would like to modify the `\possessivecite` command of the `harvard` package to automatically add the possessive ' (just an apostrophe) in citations when the author's last name ends in s/sh/sj/rs/z. When the author's name ends in any other letters, the possessive should be just s (no apostrophe).

Is this even possible?

Comment: The same problem for `biblatex` and author year styles has been addressed in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14785/4483).

Answer (score 2):

The possessive `'s` is hard-coded into `harvard.sty`. You could modify the code, including the appropriate tests for the text, but I suspect this is more effort than it is worth. As Audrey has commented, switching to `biblatex` is probably the best long-term solution here.