# Biblatex: venue can be cleared but eventdate not

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I successfully can clear fields and lists with the 
    `clearfield`
or 
    `clearlist` 
command using:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{venue}\clearfield{eventdate}\clearfield{eprint}\clearfield{date}}
```

but sadly it doesn't work for eventdate. I tried to clear it via biber mapping but `EVENTDATE` doesn't exist in biber. Hence, I assume that the field is converted biblatex- internally and I have to clear other fields than eventdate.

Can anybody give me a hint?

P.S.: Sorry for not having a MWE yet. I have a deadline today for the document

Comment: Try `\clearfield{eventyear}`. The date fields are internally decomposed into their year, month and day parts.

Comment: Excellent. That did the job. Would you mind changing your comment to an answer? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex` decomposes `date` fields internally into their parts `year`, `month` and `day`.

It is normally enough to get rid of the year field, since `biblatex` will not show dates that miss the year.

You should thus be good with

```
\clearfield{eventyear}
```

---

Biber's sourcemapping should also work

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=eventdate, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This has the advantage that the field is not parsed by Biber and you don't get warnings if the date is malformed.

Comment: See also [Biblatex: Suppressing urldate does not work (\clearfield)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278890/35864) where the accepted answer offers another way out that does not work here. There is also [Excessive fields in biblatex chicago author-date style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147749/35864)